# finde $\mathbb P(S_n=k)$ for $(S_n)$ being a random walk.

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-walk

Let $p\in (0,1)$ fixed. Let $S_n$ a random walk on $\mathbb Z$ starting at $0$ and s.t. $$\mathbb P(S_n=k\mid S_{n-1}=k-1)=p\quad \text{and}\quad \mathbb P(S_n=k\mid S_{n-1}=k+1)=1-p,\quad k\in\mathbb Z.$$
Can I find a closed form of $$f_n(k)=\mathbb P(S_n=k),$$
for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $k\in\mathbb Z$ ?

**Attempts**

We have that $f_0(k)=\boldsymbol 1_{\{0\}}(k)$. For $f_1$,

$$f_1(k)=\begin{cases}
p&k=1\\
1-p&k=-1\\
0&otherwise.
\end{cases}
$$

For $f_2$,

$$f_2(k)=\begin{cases}
p(1-p)&k=0\\
p^2&k=2\\
(1-p)^2&k=-2\\
0&otherwise.
\end{cases}
$$

For $f_3$
$$f_3(k)=\begin{cases}
p^3&k=3\\
p^2(1-p)&k=1\\
p(1-p)^2&k=-1\\
(1-p)^3&k=-3\\
0&otherwise.
\end{cases}
$$

I highly suspect that $f_n(k)=p^s(1-p)^t$ for $s+t=n$, but I'm no so sure how to find $s$ and $t$ depending on $k$. Is there any simple way to compute it ?

Comment: $f_2$ and $f_3$ are wrong. $f_2(0)=2p(1-p)$ and $f_3(-1)=3(1-p)^2p$ and $f_3(1)=3p^2(1-p)$. In fact, $S_n\sim \mathcal B(n,p)$ on $\{-n,-n+2,-n+4,,...,n\}$

Comment: Ok great, thank you. But is there a way to prove "mathematically" that $\mathbb P\{S_=k\}=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ with $k$ and $n$ with the right conditions with the information I have ? For example induction, but I'm not so sure how to do in my situation... @Surb

Comment: You can do induction with : $f_n(k)=p \;f_{n-1}(k-1) + (1-p)f_{n-1}(k+1)  $ to prove:
 $f_{2m}(2k)=\binom{2m}{k+m}p^{m+k}(1-p)^{m-k} $ and 
 $f_{2m+1}(2k+1)=\binom{2m+1}{k+m+1}p^{m+k + 1}(1-p)^{m-k} $.
We start from $m = 0$ and increment over $m$ for the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb P\{S_n=k\}=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ is wrong.

If you take $s$ positive steps and $t$ negative steps in some pattern then you have an outcome of $S_n=k$ with $n=s+t$ and $k=s-t$, so $s=(n+k)/2$ and $t=(n-k)/2$, which answers your actual question "I'm not so sure how to find $s$ and $t$ depending on $k$".

Each particular pattern of $s$ positive and $t$ negative steps has probability $p^s(1-p)^t$.

The number of patterns of $s$ positive steps and $t$ negative steps is $\binom{s+t}{s} =\binom{n}{(n+k)/2}$, taking this to be $0$ when $(n+k)/2$ or $n$ are not integers or $n<0$ or $|k|>n$. Note that $n$ and $k$ must have the same parity for a pattern to be possible, and that $k$ can be negative.

So  $$\mathbb P\{S_n=k\}=\binom{s+t}{s}p^s(1-p)^{t}=\binom{n}{(n+k)/2}p^{(n+k)/2}(1-p)^{(n-k)/2}.$$